# Скрыть элемент, если в соседнем div есть ссылка с определенным class?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать `p` с классом `ays_restart_button_p` `display: none`, если в `div` с классом `ays_score_message` есть ссылка с классом `calss_dalee`? Этот блок собирается не сразу, а когда пользователь ответит на все вопросы в quiz (без перезагрузки страницы). Ниже приведу `html` структуру:

```
<div class="ays_quiz_results_page">
    <div class="ays_score_message">
        <p>
            <a class="calss_dalee" href="/tehnicheskaya/c1-projden/">Далее</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ays_message"></div>
    <p class="ays_score animated tada"></p>
    <div class="ays-progress third">
        <span class="ays-progress-value third"></span>
        <div class="ays-progress-bg third">
            <div class="ays-progress-bar third"></div>                
        </div>            
    </div>
    <p class="ays_restart_button_p"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно проверять вот так:

```js
function checkElem () {
  $('.ays_score_message a').hasClass("calss_dalee") && $('.ays_restart_button_p').hide();
}

$('#add').on('click', ()=> {
  $('.ays_score_message').append('<p><a class="calss_dalee" href="/tehnicheskaya/c1-projden/">Далее</a><p>');
  checkElem();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ays_quiz_results_page">
    <div class="ays_score_message">
    </div>
    <div class="ays_message"></div>
    <p class="ays_score animated tada"></p>
    <div class="ays-progress third">
        <span class="ays-progress-value third"></span>
        <div class="ays-progress-bg third">
            <div class="ays-progress-bar third"></div>                
        </div>            
    </div>
    <p class="ays_restart_button_p">Visible Message</p>
</div>

<button id="add">Add link</button>
```

Comment: Не срабатывает (

Comment: А в какой момент вы проверяете? Можете добавить воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: Добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: Все ровно не пойму, как собрать код (

Comment: Мне сложно подсказать не видя что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: Пример полностью воспроизводимый. Html структура такая же. Единственное что, как я и описала в вопросе, этот блок собирается не сразу при загрузке страницы.

Comment: Я сделала по событию, но теперь у меня скрывается ays_restart_button_p даже когда класса calss_dalee в ays_score_message нет

Comment: Не работает, потому что <p><a class="calss_dalee" href="/tehnicheskaya/c1-projden/">Далее</a><p> подгружается через несколько секунд, после нажатия на кнопку. Надо как то отследить событие изменение содержимого ays_score_message... но как?

Answer (score 1):

Если надо отследить событие изменения содержимого, например: `<div class="ays_score_message">` , то можно сделать так.

```
function checkElem () {
  jQuery('.ays_score_message a').hasClass("calss_dalee") && jQuery('.ays_restart_button_p').hide();
}

jQuery('.ays_score_message').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    console.log(this);
      checkElem();
});
```